# converting .doc files to pdf files using python

Tags: python, automation

Am trying to convert the .doc files to pdf files .Below is the code .The problem is if there are 5 files it is converting only 3 of them after it is getting paused . sometimes am getting the below issue

Error occurred while converting 23KB.doc: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Sorry, we couldn’t find your file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?\r (D:\...\//PrintToPdfPowerShell/23KB.doc)', 'wdmain11.chm', 24654, -2146823114), None)

Could anyone help me in this issue .what is suspect in background files are not closing properly after converting into pdf .If that is the case could anyone give me the solution

```
Below are the .doc files that am trying to convert to pdf
05/26/2023  05:55 AM             9,281 11KB.docx
05/26/2023  05:55 AM            28,672 12KB.doc
05/26/2023  05:55 AM            36,352 15KB.doc
05/26/2023  05:56 AM           174,592 170KB.doc
05/26/2023  05:55 AM            36,352 23KB.doc
```

Below is the code

```
import os
import win32com.client

items = os.listdir(r'D:/PrintToPdfPowerShell/')
for file in items:
    if file.endswith('.doc') and not file.startswith('~$'):
        print(file)
        word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
        word_app.Visible = False
        try:
            doc = word_app.Documents.Open(r'D:/PrintToPdfPowerShell/' + file, ReadOnly=True, NoEncodingDialog=True)
            doc.SaveAs(r'D:/PrintToPdfPowerShell/' + os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.pdf', FileFormat=17)
            doc.Close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred while converting {file}: {str(e)}")
word_app.Quit()
```

Comment: Could you please add the logic to the code

Comment: sometimes am getting this error "Error occurred while converting 12KB.doc: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Command failed', 'wdmain11.chm', 36966, -2146824090), None)"